# Wickr install Fails:

Tags: dpkg, 15.10

I tried to install the Wickr's deb package available in the app's website on Ubuntu 15.10 and I get the following message:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i wickr_2.3.5_amd64.deb 
sudo: unable to resolve host martin-Hp
[sudo] password for martin: 
(Reading database ... 328263 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wickr_2.3.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wickr (2.3.5-7) over (2.3.5-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wickr:
 wickr depends on libicu52; however:
  Package libicu52:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wickr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wickr
```

As you may notice, this doesn't give me much information about what's going on, Does anyone know how to solve it?

Best!

Comment: There's already something there. Sudo can't figure out your computer. Please post the output of `cat /etc/hostname` and also `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: `dpkg` doesn't automatically resolve dependencies when installing .deb files: you may want to try using the Software Center or `gdebi` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The packages isn't available in the Wily repositories. You can try the Vivid version:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that, install your deb file again, if necessary.

---

Another solution is, change the dependencies in your DEB file to use `libicu55`, that's available for Wily.

1. Extract the DEB package

   ```
   cd
   mkdir deb$$
   cp wickr_2.3.5_amd64.deb deb$$
   cd deb$$
   dpkg-deb -x wickr_2.3.5_amd64.deb  deb
   cd deb
   dpkg-deb -e ../wickr_2.3.5_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Change the dependencies:

   ```
   sed -i 's/libicu52/libicu55/' DEBIAN/control
   ```
3. Re-pack the DEB file and install

   ```
   cd ..
   sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
   sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
   ```

Comment: Tried this with Ubuntu 16.04, but it did not work. More unmet dependencies, which I could not resolve even by installing some missing packages (i.e. `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good` for `gstreamer-plugins0.10-good`). I think Wickr Inc. should work on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
wickr: Depends: libavutil54 but it is not installed
       Depends: libx264-142 but it is not installed
```

Got it working on Ubuntu 15.10 by downloading the two missing packages with a web browser and installing them with Ubuntu Software Centre:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libx264
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavutil54

I initially found libavutil54 on the Debian Packages website so try that if the second link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered more or less the same dependency missing issues and a couple more. I tried finding libs but a bit hard to find it and at the end I got error refusing the application to open up due to error is loading shared libs. So I though to put most of the libs' direct download link for users to download and install easily and is as follows :

- [libicu52](http://wget%20http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb)
- [libx264-142](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/x264/libx264-142_0.142.2389+git956c8d8-2_amd64.deb)
- [libx264-148](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/x264/libx264-148_0.148.2643+git5c65704-1_amd64.deb)
- [Libavutil-54](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libav/libavutil54_11.9-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb)

you can download the above links and install libs by executing commands in the directory where your downloaded libs

`sudo dpkg -i "deb file name u downloaded"`

Finally you may need to install the libgstreamer0.10 for the application to open up without errors by issuing the cmd as follows :

```
`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev`
```

Now you may try installing wickr deb again.